# MsiPackage isn’t installed anymore using Wix and Burn

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bundle, burn

While adding a new prerequesite to my bootstrapper bundle I accidently  broke my installer which result in not installing my internal msi. I was starting my journey with Wix 3.8.1128.

With a bootstrapper setup I install .Net 4.6.1 and my own msi. Since we need the Hotfixrollup for 4.6.1 from Microsoft also I had to update my installer. Since I didn’t manage it to install the hotfix rollup like my msi I added it as mba-prerequesite (http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/4161-allow-more-than-one-mbaprereq/) Therfore I had to update Wix to Wix 3.10.2.2516 since my previous installed Wix didn’t understood “bal: PrereqSupportPackage”

The bundle.wxs now looks like this:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx46FullInternal" />
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="Net46License.rtf" />

<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
  <Payload SourceFile="Licenses\NetfxLicense.rtf" Name="Net46License.rtf"/>
 <Some other payload like resource file for the custom bootstrapper ui>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>

<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx46FullInternal' />
  <ExePackage Id="Netfx461HotfixRollup" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
        DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Hotfixrollup"
        DetectCondition="(Netfx4FullVersion >= &quot;4.6.01073&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion>=&quot;4.6.01073&quot;))"
        InstallCommand="/passive /norestart"
        SourceFile="..\..\..\..\Common\PayloadBundle\NDP461-KB3139551-x86-x64-ENU.exe" bal:PrereqSupportPackage="yes">
        <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot" Value="1641" />
        <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot" Value="3010" />
        <ExitCode Behavior="success" Value="0" />
  </ExePackage>
  <RollbackBoundary />
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\..\..\bin\Setup\Release\en-US\certified\MyMsi.msi" Id="SetupMSI" Cache="yes" DisplayInternalUI="no" SuppressSignatureVerification ="yes" Visible="no" >
     <MsiProperty Name="SETUPLANGLIST" Value="[STARTLCID]" />
     <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLATIONFOLDER]" />
     <Payload SourceFile="..\..\..\Common\Localization\Transforms\de-DE\de-DE.mst" Id="GERMANTRANSFORM" ></Payload>
     <MsiProperty Name="TRANSFORMS" Value="[TRANSFORMNAME]" />
  </MsiPackage>
</Chain>
```

When I run this setup on different systems, i.e. with installed .Net 4.6.1, with installed Hotfix, without etc. the log always looks fine:

```
Snips:
[0870:0874][2016-03-16T15:52:56]i052: Condition '(Netfx4FullVersion >= "4.6") AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion>="4.6"))' evaluates to false.
[0870:0874][2016-03-16T15:52:56]i052: Condition '(Netfx4FullVersion >= "4.6.01073") AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion>="4.6.01073"))' evaluates to false.

[0870:0874][2016-03-16T15:52:56]i101: Detected package: Netfx4FullInternal, state: Absent, cached: None

[0870:0874][2016-03-16T15:52:56]i101: Detected package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, state: Absent, cached: None

[0870:0874][2016-03-16T15:52:56]i101: Detected package: SetupMSI, state: Absent, cached: None

[….]

[0870:0874][2016-03-16T15:52:58]i201: Planned package: Netfx4FullInternal, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: None

[0870:0874][2016-03-16T15:52:58]i201: Planned package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: None

[0870:0874][2016-03-16T15:52:58]i201: Planned package: SetupMSI, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None

[…]

Verified acquired payload: Netfx4FullInternal at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Netfx4FullInternal, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\83D048D171FF44A3CAD9B422137656F585295866\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe.

[091C:0930][2016-03-16T15:53:22]i305: Verified acquired payload: Netfx461HotfixRollup at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Netfx461HotfixRollup, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3AFF8231798A7A66EF10BAF8B4B4BCF1CE29874E\NDP461-KB3139551-x86-x64-ENU.exe.

[091C:0920][2016-03-16T15:53:22]i301: Applying execute package: Netfx4FullInternal, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\83D048D171FF44A3CAD9B422137656F585295866\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\83D048D171FF44A3CAD9B422137656F585295866\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /passive /norestart'

[0870:0874][2016-03-16T15:59:11]i319: Applied execute package: Netfx4FullInternal, result: 0x0, restart: None

[091C:0920][2016-03-16T15:59:11]i301: Applying execute package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3AFF8231798A7A66EF10BAF8B4B4BCF1CE29874E\NDP461-KB3139551-x86-x64-ENU.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3AFF8231798A7A66EF10BAF8B4B4BCF1CE29874E\NDP461-KB3139551-x86-x64-ENU.exe" /passive /norestart'

[0870:0874][2016-03-16T16:03:29]i319: Applied execute package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, result: 0x0, restart: None

[091C:0920][2016-03-16T16:03:29]i351: Removing cached package: Netfx4FullInternal, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\83D048D171FF44A3CAD9B422137656F585295866\

[091C:0920][2016-03-16T16:03:29]i351: Removing cached package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3AFF8231798A7A66EF10BAF8B4B4BCF1CE29874E\

[091C:0920][2016-03-16T16:03:29]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e2db8a84-7452-4c88-ba7f-ef0799a8e9b0}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No

[091C:0920][2016-03-16T16:03:29]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e2db8a84-7452-4c88-ba7f-ef0799a8e9b0}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No

[0870:0874][2016-03-16T16:03:29]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

[0870:0874][2016-03-16T16:03:29]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[0870:0874][2016-03-16T16:03:29]i000: The prerequisites were successfully installed. The bootstrapper application will be reloaded.

[…]
```

Here the prereqs have been successfully installed. The bootstrapper has been reloaded. The system itself did no restart. Then, the process starts again. But my internal msi is never installed.

Since we need this setup I rolled back my changes but let Wix 3.10.2.2516 remain on the build servers.

Now my setup, even when it in toto is exactly the same as it was before, is not able to install my internal msi package. So I’m afraid something changed from Wix 3.8 to 3.10 which may brings a design failure in our setup to surface.
We are dealing with several detection events to set up our ui according to package states. 
So I’m wondering what changed in Wix 3.10.2 and how to solve my problem?

EDIT and UPDATE:
The whole log looks like this:

```
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:40]i001: Burn v3.10.2.2516, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\{4045AD9D-EBFB-40DA-A3A7-8AA715BF55B3}\.cr\MySetup.exe
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:40]i009: Command Line: '"-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\admin\Desktop\MySetup.exe"'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\MySetup.exe'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\MySetup_2.0_20160318130640.log'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:41]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'MySetup 2.0'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:41]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'MyComp'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:41]i000: Loading prerequisite bootstrapper application because managed host could not be loaded, error: 0x80070490.
[09BC:09D4][2016-03-18T13:06:41]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
[09BC:09D4][2016-03-18T13:06:41]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '2.0.6858.48481'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:42]i100: Detect begin, 3 packages
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:42]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:42]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:42]i052: Condition '(Netfx4FullVersion >= "4.6") AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion>="4.6"))' evaluates to false.
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:42]i052: Condition '(Netfx4FullVersion >= "4.6.01073") AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion>="4.6.01073"))' evaluates to false.
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:42]i101: Detected package: Netfx4FullInternal, state: Absent, cached: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:42]i101: Detected package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, state: Absent, cached: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:42]i101: Detected package: MyInternalSetupMSI, state: Absent, cached: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:42]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:44]i200: Plan begin, 3 packages, action: Install
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:44]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Netfx4FullInternal
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_Netfx4FullInternal' to value 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\MySetup_2.0_20160318130640_000_Netfx4FullInternal.log'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:44]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Netfx461HotfixRollup
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_Netfx461HotfixRollup' to value 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\MySetup_2.0_20160318130640_001_Netfx461HotfixRollup.log'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:44]i201: Planned package: Netfx4FullInternal, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:44]i201: Planned package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:44]i201: Planned package: MyInternalSetupMSI, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:44]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:44]i300: Apply begin
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:44]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:51]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:06:51]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:06:51]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:06:52]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:06:52]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:07:04]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:07:04]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:07:04]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\{B3F81685-3E6A-41D1-95D9-641F8276F3FF}\.be\MySetup.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}\MySetup.exe'
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:07:04]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}, version: 2.0.6858.48481
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:07:04]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[09BC:0BF4][2016-03-18T13:07:04]i336: Acquiring container: WixAttachedContainer, copy from: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\MySetup.exe
[09BC:0BF4][2016-03-18T13:07:06]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\'
[0A5C:0A70][2016-03-18T13:07:07]i305: Verified acquired payload: Netfx4FullInternal at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Netfx4FullInternal, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\83D048D171FF44A3CAD9B422137656F585295866\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe.
[0A5C:0A70][2016-03-18T13:07:08]i305: Verified acquired payload: Netfx461HotfixRollup at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Netfx461HotfixRollup, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3AFF8231798A7A66EF10BAF8B4B4BCF1CE29874E\NDP461-KB3139551-x86-x64-ENU.exe.
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:07:08]i301: Applying execute package: Netfx4FullInternal, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\83D048D171FF44A3CAD9B422137656F585295866\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\83D048D171FF44A3CAD9B422137656F585295866\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /passive /norestart'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:11:19]i319: Applied execute package: Netfx4FullInternal, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:11:19]i301: Applying execute package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3AFF8231798A7A66EF10BAF8B4B4BCF1CE29874E\NDP461-KB3139551-x86-x64-ENU.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3AFF8231798A7A66EF10BAF8B4B4BCF1CE29874E\NDP461-KB3139551-x86-x64-ENU.exe" /passive /norestart'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i319: Applied execute package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i351: Removing cached package: Netfx4FullInternal, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\83D048D171FF44A3CAD9B422137656F585295866\
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i351: Removing cached package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3AFF8231798A7A66EF10BAF8B4B4BCF1CE29874E\
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i000: The prerequisites were successfully installed. The bootstrapper application will be reloaded.
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i006: Bootstrapper application requested to be reloaded.
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[09BC:0B38][2016-03-18T13:14:50]i000: Setting string variable 'STARTLCID' to value '1031'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i100: Detect begin, 3 packages
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i000: Setting string variable 'Netfx4x64FullVersion' to value '4.6.01073'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i000: Setting string variable 'Netfx4FullVersion' to value '4.6.01073'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i052: Condition '(Netfx4FullVersion >= "4.6") AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion>="4.6"))' evaluates to true.
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i000: DetectPackageComplete State Present
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i000: DetectPackageComplete Status 0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i052: Condition '(Netfx4FullVersion >= "4.6.01073") AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion>="4.6.01073"))' evaluates to true.
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i000: DetectPackageComplete State Present
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i000: DetectPackageComplete Status 0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i000: DetectPackageComplete State Absent
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i000: DetectPackageComplete Status 0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i101: Detected package: Netfx4FullInternal, state: Present, cached: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i101: Detected package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, state: Present, cached: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i101: Detected package: MyInternalSetupMSI, state: Absent, cached: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[09BC:0B38][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i000: SetupDialogWorkflow
[09BC:0B38][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i000: Setting string variable 'INSTALLATIONFOLDER' to value 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyComp\My Setup\1.0'
[09BC:0B38][2016-03-18T13:14:51]i000: Setting string variable 'STARTLCID' to value '2057'
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:27]i200: Plan begin, 3 packages, action: Cache
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:27]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Netfx4FullInternal
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:27]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Netfx461HotfixRollup
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:27]i201: Planned package: Netfx4FullInternal, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:27]i201: Planned package: Netfx461HotfixRollup, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:27]i201: Planned package: MyInternalSetupMSI, state: Absent, default requested: Cache, ba requested: Cache, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:27]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:27]i300: Apply begin
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:15:27]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:15:27]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:15:27]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:15:33]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:15:33]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}, options: 0x4, disable resume: No
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:15:33]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}, version: 2.0.6858.48481
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:15:33]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[09BC:095C][2016-03-18T13:15:33]i336: Acquiring container: WixAttachedContainer, copy from: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\MySetup.exe
[0A5C:0A70][2016-03-18T13:15:34]i305: Verified acquired payload: MyInternalSetupMSI at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\MyInternalSetupMSI, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{AB62269F-C1BF-44DA-A3DF-B5806E7D066F}v2.0.6858.48481\MyInternalSetupMSI.msi.
[0A5C:0A70][2016-03-18T13:15:34]i305: Verified acquired payload: GERMANTRANSFORM at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\GERMANTRANSFORM, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{AB62269F-C1BF-44DA-A3DF-B5806E7D066F}v2.0.6858.48481\de-DE.mst.
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:15:34]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:15:34]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:15:34]i352: Removing cached bundle: {22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}\
[0A5C:0A60][2016-03-18T13:15:34]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:34]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: INSTALLATIONFOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\MyComp\My Setup\1.0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: Netfx4FullVersion = 4.6.01073
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: Netfx4x64FullVersion = 4.6.01073
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: STARTLCID = 2057
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: VersionNT64 = 6.1.0.0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 4
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleFileVersion = 2.0.6858.48481
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleLastUsedSource = C:\Users\admin\Desktop\
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\MySetup_2.0_20160318130640.log
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_Netfx461HotfixRollup = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\MySetup_2.0_20160318130640_001_Netfx461HotfixRollup.log
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_Netfx4FullInternal = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\MySetup_2.0_20160318130640_000_Netfx4FullInternal.log
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = MyComp
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = MySetup 2.0
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\admin\Desktop\MySetup.exe
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = C:\Users\admin\Desktop\
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {22d938da-2fa9-4609-beeb-86c3469d5eeb}
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessFolder = C:\Users\admin\Desktop\
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessPath = C:\Users\admin\Desktop\MySetup.exe
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 2.0.6858.48481
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i410: Variable: WixStdBALanguageId = 1033
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:38]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

We are reacting on some events, but worked fine before Wix 3.10.2.

```
private void Model_DetectPackageComplete(object sender, DetectPackageCompleteEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.PackageId != "MyInternalSetupMSI")
  {
    return;
  }

  switch (e.State)
  {
    case PackageState.Present:
      this.currentLaunchAction = LaunchAction.Uninstall;
      break;
    case PackageState.Absent:
      this.currentLaunchAction = LaunchAction.Install;
      break;
    case PackageState.Superseded:
      this.currentLaunchAction = LaunchAction.Unknown;
    break;
  }
} 


private void DetectPackageComplete(object sender, DetectPackageCompleteEventArgs e)
{
  this.onLoggerAction(LogLevel.Verbose, string.Format("DetectPackageComplete State {0}", e.State));
  this.onLoggerAction(LogLevel.Verbose, string.Format("DetectPackageComplete Status {0}", e.Status));
  if (e.PackageId == "MyInternalSetupMSI")
  {
    this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.DetectPackageComplete(e.State)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a full log?  It's hard to tell exactly what's going wrong.  I can't tell whether your MBA is never loading (in which case the error code and your BootstrapperCore.config would be needed) or whether your MSI is just not getting installed (how did you setup upgrades in the MSI and did you increment the version?).

Comment: I added the full log. Our bootstrapper does not allow upgrade/downgrades. When a setup like us is installed we abort the process. So we can't have a mixture - hopefully. The version of the bundle and the msi is alsways the same  and unique and depends on the build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
[09BC:09C0][2016-03-18T13:15:27]i201: Planned package: MyInternalSetupMSI, state: Absent, default requested: Cache, ba requested: Cache, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
```

The `Install` value changed in v3.10, so that value is now `Cache`.  Whenever you upgrade the WiX version in v3.x, you need to recompile your BA.  We are in the process of removing this requirement in v4.

Comment: I had still the old BootstrapperCore.dll referenced. I've updated this ref to 3.10.x and itr worked on my local system fine. Thank you very much

Comment: @Sean Hall: I have also updated my wix from v3.7 to v3.11 and now my exe is not installing only due this cache issue. How should I resole it ?